# Why is ui-router not woking with img tag

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to ui-router.
I am trying to navigate to models state. When I take the first apporach with button it works fine but it fails when I do the same with img tag.

```
 //it works:
 <a ui-sref="models"> 
     <button class="btn btn-primary">goto models state</button>
</a>

//below code does not work:
<a ui-serf="models">
    <img src="/content/images/_genericDevice.png" />
</a>
```

Can anybody explain why is this so ?

Comment: the state models is a basic state, no nesting and abstract case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is intentional, but you have a typo:

```
<a ui-serf="models">
```

`ui-serf` should be `ui-sref`